# how to pass array size to function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

just I want to ask how can I pass array size to throw function to set size of my game recoreds the only reason I am not using vector because I will base this recored to PMI lib and it doesn't support C++ Constrainers because it written in C that's why I use array

```
void playGame(int max_streak_length)
{
    int tracker =0 ;
    const int arrsize  = max_streak_length;

    int gameRecored[arrsize]={0};


    while( tracker < 4)
    {

        Craps games;

        if( games.Play()== true)
        {
            tracker++;
        }
        else
            if(tracker >0)
        {
            gameRecored[tracker-1]++;
            tracker = 0;
        }

    }
    gameRecored[tracker-1]++;
    int v= 0;


}
```

Comment: make a dynamic array, or use a vector? use a template function?

Comment: This is C++.  Why don't you use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not support the variable length array feature available in C.99. However, C++ offers `std::vector<>` which is as easy to use, and some may say safer.

```
    std::vector<int> gameRecored(arrsize, 0);
```

You can use `gameRecored` as an array like you do in your current code, and it will clean itself up when the function call returns.

Answer (score 0):

you can't not define an array whose size is a VARIABLE. If you want a dynamic size, you should use operator new, just like this:

```
int mysize = 10;
int* array = new int[mysize];
```

the variable mysize can be a dynamic number, such as function parameter.
If your array will never change its size, you can use :

```
int array[10];
```

remember, if you use operator new, you must use operator delete to delete your array when you don't need it.

Hop can help you.

Comment: how can i fill them all 0

Comment: As @paddy said before me, using `std::vector` would be even better than making a dynamic array with `new`.